# ArcScene rendering only in greyscale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I'm new to ArcScene so maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see any colors in my ArcScene views. I've attached 3 screenshots, one from ArcMap showing DEM and hillshade working just fine, and 2 from ArcScene that show a lot of grayscale rendering in both raster (DEM) and vector layers (streets, buildings) despite changing the symbology in preferences.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image: graydem[![][2]][2]]

[image: grayDEMagain]